# How to use AJAX to add quick reply in WEBCHAT discussion

Tags: php, ajax

I'm developing a webchat using PHP and i want to use AJAX to post discussion replys.

How can i do that...?

Comment: What have you tried? Post some code. Check  this [metaSO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question) and [Jon Skeet: Coding Blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) on how to write and ask a good question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want realtime chat with support to browsers that don't support Web-Sockets then try Comet-Programming with Ajax Long-Pulling. 
I am a PHP-Guy so can recommend you a PHP-Comet-Server link
http://sourceforge.net/projects/comet/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First get it working without ajax / the normal way and as soon as all functionalities are there, you can add ajax where it streamlines the visitor's process.